# Changing color of the second letter of a link

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I've been trying to figure out how to target the second character of a link and change its color to red.

And I'm trying to target the **second letter**.

Without the `nth-child(2)`, my code successfully changes the color of the whole link to red.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".header-title-text").find("a:nth-child(2)").css({
    color: 'red'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header-title-text'>
  <a>title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly add color to a letter, you need to rap it in some HTML element like `span` and then you can add the color.

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var secLetter = $(".header-title-text").find("a").text().split('')[1];
  $(".header-title-text").find("a").html($(".header-title-text").find("a").html().replace(secLetter, "<span class='red'>" + secLetter + "</span>"));
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-title-text">
  <a href="abc.com">title</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. 

What does the .split('')[1] do?

Comment: `.split('')`, split each letter of the string into an array, and `[1]` will get the first index data which is `i` in your case as the array index starts from 0.